# How can I access child components of different types in order in an Angular 2 component?

Tags: angular, typescript

Lets say I have a component, `Carousel` that can contain other components of a set of types e.g. `CarouselImage`, `CarouselText` etc.

I want to do something like this ...

```
type CarouselItem = CarouselImage | CarouselText;
```

and then in the component

```
@ContentChildren(CarouselItem) items: QueryList<CarouselItem>;
```

However, this does not work. I undertsand the following is possible ...

```
@ContentChildren(CarouselImage) imgItems: QueryList<CarouselImage>;
@ContentChildren(CarouselText) txtItems: QueryList<CarouselText>;
```

but here the order is lost.

What is the best way to access the child components without losing the order?

Answer (score 0):

How about that:

```
export interface CarouselItem{
  public getItem<T>():T;
}
```

And then you have to implement that interface in your CarouselImage and CarouselText like that:

```
export class CarouselText implements CarouselItem{

  public getItem<CarouselText>:CarouselText{
    return this;

  }
}
```

In your CarouselComponent you can just call the getItem() function on any value in the list.

Define that list like that:

```
items:QueryList<CarouselItem>;
```

Example filling:

```
items.push(new QueryText());
items.push(new QueryImage());
```

If both of these classes implement the QueryItem interface and your component calls the method this interface has, it should perfectly work! This is the concept of interfaces and generics.

Comment: Unfortunately `@ContentChildren` cannot accept an interface as an argument, it ives the same error as when you use a union type (as in the question)